# CSS Grid for a table with dynamic number of columns while only some of them have set widths

Tags: css, css-grid

In the below snippet. I am trying to make a grid layout that will replace a table. This is easy enough in this article.

https://medium.com/evodeck/responsive-data-tables-with-css-grid-3c58ecf04723

however. the desired layout has a few curve balls

1. Users will be adding and removing columns at runtime. we are looking for css which will not require us to know the number of columns in advanced.
2. The name columns should always be 50% of the total rows' width

*this is actually pretty easy in flexbox but i really want to switch to css grid*

> run the code snippet below. to simulate a solution

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(4em, 1fr));
}
.item {
  height: 3em;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containers">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item name">This col should always take 50% but has a varying text length</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<button class="row">Add Row</button>
<button class="add">Add Column</button>
<button class="rm">Remove Column</button>

<hr>
<hr>

<p><strong>With every new row</strong></p>
<ul>
    <li>All columns should line up vertically like a table</li>
    <li>the name column should always take the 50% width of total row</li>
    <li>adding a column should still follow the rules above</li>
    <li>How can i elips or wrap <strong>overflow text</strong> in this kind of layout</li>
</ul>

<script>
    const addButton = document.querySelector('button.add');
    const rmButton = document.querySelector('button.rm');
    const rowButton = document.querySelector('button.row');
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    const lorem = `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.`;
    
    // listen
    addButton.addEventListener("click", addColumn);
    rmButton.addEventListener("click", rmColumn);
    rowButton.addEventListener("click", rowColumn);

    function addColumn(event) {
        $(".container").each(function () {
            const newCol = document.createElement("div");
            newCol.className += "item";
            $(this).append(newCol)
        });
    }
    function rmColumn(event) {
        $(".container").each(function () {
            this.removeChild(this.lastElementChild);
        });
    }
    function rowColumn(event) {
        const randLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
        const newRowClass = "new-row" + randLength;
        const newRow = container.cloneNode(true);
        newRow.className += ` ${newRowClass}`;
        container.parentNode.appendChild(newRow);
        const newRowName = document.querySelector(`.${newRowClass} .name`);
        newRowName.innerHTML = lorem.slice(0, randLength);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

set template columns only for the first 2 columns, and set the remaining columns as auto columns:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(4em, 1fr) 50% repeat(auto-fit, minmax(4em, 1fr));
}
.item {
  height: 3em;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containers">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item name">This col should always take 50% but has a varying text length</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<button class="row">Add Row</button>
<button class="add">Add Column</button>
<button class="rm">Remove Column</button>

<hr>
<hr>

<p><strong>With every new row</strong></p>
<ul>
    <li>All columns should line up vertically like a table</li>
    <li>the name column should always take the 50% width of total row</li>
    <li>adding a column should still follow the rules above</li>
    <li>How can i elips or wrap <strong>overflow text</strong> in this kind of layout</li>
</ul>

<script>
    const addButton = document.querySelector('button.add');
    const rmButton = document.querySelector('button.rm');
    const rowButton = document.querySelector('button.row');
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    const lorem = `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.`;
    
    // listen
    addButton.addEventListener("click", addColumn);
    rmButton.addEventListener("click", rmColumn);
    rowButton.addEventListener("click", rowColumn);

    function addColumn(event) {
        $(".container").each(function () {
            const newCol = document.createElement("div");
            newCol.className += "item";
            $(this).append(newCol)
        });
    }
    function rmColumn(event) {
        $(".container").each(function () {
            this.removeChild(this.lastElementChild);
        });
    }
    function rowColumn(event) {
        const randLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
        const newRowClass = "new-row" + randLength;
        const newRow = container.cloneNode(true);
        newRow.className += ` ${newRowClass}`;
        container.parentNode.appendChild(newRow);
        const newRowName = document.querySelector(`.${newRowClass} .name`);
        newRowName.innerHTML = lorem.slice(0, randLength);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: when you add rows. the columns are not lining up (in your snippet)